# Alternative for request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath()

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat8

I am migrating Java web application from Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 8. In the application ,on a button click, pdf gets created first  in 'Workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Project' folder if it does not exists and then opened in a new window.

This functionality works fine Tomcat 6 and 7 .
But in Tomcat 8 ,pdf gets created but its not opening on first click(getting 404 error) . On second or third click it's getting displayed.

Below code is used to get the path of the pdf location:

String path = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("//MyPdf.pdf");

Hard coding of pdf path is working fine in Tomcat 8 as well .  I am not able to understand what is the issue , suggest some alternative for the above code.

Comment: Log what the resulting path is. One slash, case-sensitive names, and tomcat user rights, and such.

Comment: Path is correct , because if click on the button when pdf already exists its working fine . Getting this issue only when pdf is generated and then opening

Comment: Check that the generating closes the file properly.

Comment: @Joop  using document.close() and writer.close() [using Pdfwriter] after document creation.   If I use the mentioned code any where in the flow but not use the value returned rather than I if hard code the path  then also its not  working .  But I need to use the above or some alternative

Answer (score 0):

I can see **2 slashes** before your file name.

```
String path = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("//MyPdf.pdf");
```

Below code should work.

```
String path = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/MyPdf.pdf");
```